# Start Python with Optimizer Flag

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

is there a possibility to start the nodes that are written in Python with the optimization flag `-O`?

I want to provide two different builds: debug and release. The optimizer flag should only be set in the release build mode.

Thank you,
Best Regards
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266366/start-python-with-optimizer-flag/) by [ricorod](https://answers.ros.org/users/31187/ricorod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found one solution:

Adding the following attribute to the node in the launch file:

```
launch-prefix="python $(arg optimization_flags)"
```

with

```
<arg name="optimization_flags" value="-OO" />
```

---

Originally posted by [ricorod](https://answers.ros.org/users/31187/ricorod/) with karma: 11 on 2017-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1